# What are the consequences of a larger heroku slug size?

Tags: heroku

I have some decisions to make around where I store an app's static image assets (~300mb). The most convenient place is inside the app and checked into source control. But another option could be to place them in an external cloud bucket.

If these assets are added to the app, checked into source control, and are pushed to Heorku as part of the slug, what will the consequences be, if any, for heroku deployments?

#### What I already know

- I know already that it's under the 500mb soft limit for Heroku apps, so I think that should be okay.

#### Things I don't know

- Will it add a few minutes to every deployment?
- Does it mean the app requires dynos with more RAM?
- Does it slow down deployments?
- Other impacts?

#### Other notes

The fast deployment times on Heroku are extremely appreciated (e.g < 2 minutes), so if increasing the slug size by 300mb would add several minutes to that time, then that would be useful info to know because it would confirm the value in avoiding that approach and storing in cloud storage instead.

Answer (score 1):

The slugsize represents the footprint of your package so the real impact is on the time required to transfer this to a Dyno.
Heroku recommends keeping this as small as possible to ensure lighter/faster deployment as well as scaling you application.

There is no impact on RAM (unless obviously the application loads somehow the images).

The overall deployment will be definitely slower, but it is difficult to quantify how many extra minutes/seconds will be necessary. This can be tested.

My advice would be to consider storing the images within the application only if it is pretty sure that the number/size of the images will not change over time. If it is not the case it might be better to plan a more scalable architecture already (storing the images on an external dedicated storage).